# Geting value of a relationship in sequelize js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get the value and returns postgres me that this column does not exist. I am not able to deal in any way.

> "column Group.participant.id does not exist"

relationship:

```
User.belongsToMany(models.group, { as: 'Member', through: { model: models.participant, unique: false}, foreignKey: 'userId', constraints: false});

Group.belongsToMany(models.user, { as: 'Group', through: { model: models.participant, unique: false}, foreignKey: 'groupId', constraints: false });

Participant.belongsTo(models.user, {
foreignKey: "userId", as: "Member"
});

Participant.belongsTo(models.group, {
foreignKey: "groupId", as: "Group"
});
```

Query/Sequelizejs:

```
const User = app.db_connect.postgres.models.user;

Group.findAll({
    include: [
    {   model: User,
        as: 'Group',
        where: {
            "participant.id": idUser
        }
        // attributes: ['name']
    }
    ]})
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(412).json({msg: error.message});
    });

});
```

Query generate:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "group"."id", "group"."name", "group"."isMain", "group"."privacy", "group"."description", "group"."img", "group"."createdAt", "group"."updatedAt", "group"."destroyTime", "group"."categoryId", "Group"."id" AS "Group.id", "Group"."name" AS "Group.name", "Group"."birthday" AS "Group.birthday", "Group"."cpf" AS "Group.cpf", "Group"."email" AS "Group.email", "Group"."img" AS "Group.img", "Group"."status" AS "Group.status", "Group"."phone" AS "Group.phone", "Group"."cellPhone" AS "Group.cellPhone", "Group"."nickName" AS "Group.nickName", "Group"."password" AS "Group.password", "Group"."found" AS "Group.found", "Group"."createdAt" AS "Group.createdAt", "Group"."updatedAt" AS "Group.updatedAt", "Group"."destroyTime" AS "Group.destroyTime", "Group.participant"."id" AS "Group.participant.id", "Group.participant"."function" AS "Group.participant.function", "Group.participant"."createdAt" AS "Group.participant.createdAt", "Group.participant"."updatedAt" AS "Group.participant.updatedAt", "Group.participant"."groupId" AS "Group.participant.groupId", "Group.participant"."userId" AS "Group.participant.userId" FROM "groups" AS "group" INNER JOIN ("participants" AS "Group.participant" INNER JOIN "users" AS "Group" ON "Group"."id" = "Group.participant"."userId") ON "group"."id" = "Group.participant"."groupId" AND ("Group"."destroyTime" IS NULL AND "Group"."participant.id" = 1) WHERE "group"."destroyTime" IS NULL;
```

Returns without the where: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/F5P3YdHf)

Answer (score 0):

Use just `id` in `where`, because in include section you work with a columns of specific model

```
Group.findAll({
  include: [{ model: User, as: 'Group',
    where: {
        "id": idUser
    }
  }]})
```